# Grails 2.0 - how to use createLinkTo in Bootstrap or background thread

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm using Grails 2.0.0, and trying to prepopulate some test data from Bootstrap.groovy. This data requires `createLinkTo` from Grails taglib.

Btw, when i'm trying to call `g.createLinkTo(...)` I getting:

```
Message: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside 
of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving
thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message,
your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this 
case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

And also, this app is going to use `createLinkTo` in background threads (event processing, send mails, etc). So I need it not only in Bootstrap.

As I understand I need to make an mock request, and bind it to current thread, but how I can do that?

Or maybe there is another way to make app links?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In grails 2 you can use the `LinkGenerator`

Have a look [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/introduction.html#whatsNew) in the Link Generation API section.

Comment: Not if you are off the request thread.  LinkGenerator and the DefaultRequestStateLookupStrategy assumes you are using it from the request thread.  The only option you have when you go to the background thread is to set your serverBasedUrl and contextPath on the LinkGenerator for it to work.  Otherwise it returns http://localhost/ for absolute URLs.  No port, no contextPath included.